# I want to replace cluster 1 as 0 and cluster 2 as 1. How can I do it?

Tags: r, k-means

**This is my input:**

```
0.0871217   0.2314687   0.3934520   
0.0206478   0.0975875   0.6195553       
0.0252821   0.2301909   0.7296519       
0.0122045   0.2448206   0.7759893   
0.0180428   0.2158894   0.6576511
```

**My code**

> Read the dataset

```
dataSet2 <- read.table(file.choose())
```

> apply kmeans(cluster=2)

```
data1<-kmeans(dataSet2,2)
```

> Aggregate

```
aggregate(dataSet2,by=list(data1$cluster),FUN=mean)
```

> Append

```
data2<-data.frame(dataSet2,data1$cluster)
```

**My output:**

```
Group.1         V1         V2         V3

1         1    0.0190443  0.1971221  0.6957119

2         2    0.0871217  0.2314687  0.3934520
```

Comment: So you need help subtracting by 1? Or am I missing something else here?

Comment: trying to implement k-means discretization technique with number of bins=2

Comment: There are 2 clusters. I want to replace cluster 1 with 0 and cluster 2 with 1

Comment: MrFlick's question is still open - it looks like you want to substract 1 from Group.1. (?)

Comment: 0.0190443  0.1971221  0.6957119 are in cluster 1 and 0.0871217  0.2314687  0.3934520 are in cluster2

Comment: I think my question is not clear. In the output dataset, I have 2 clusters: cluster1 and cluster2. cluster1 contains   0.0190443  0.1971221  0.6957119  and cluster2 contains 0.0871217  0.2314687  0.3934520. All I want to do is to replace the values of cluster 1 with 0s and cluster 2 with 1s

Comment: Yes, it still isn't clear. You are showing us the output of `aggregate` at the bottom, but what you want us to work with is the `data2` data frame, which you are cunningly hiding from us! It's good because otherwise this would be a trivially simple problem... well done for keeping us on our toes.

Comment: Also, do you want to replace the column which holds the cluster variable in your data? Or do you want to replace the values in V1, V2 and V3?

Comment: I want to replace the first row as 0 and second row as 1(first row contains  0.0190443  0.1971221  0.6957119 and second row contains 0.0871217  0.2314687  0.3934520). Secondly I am not hiding anything. data2 is the result by appending dataset2 and data1$cluster which is clearly shown in the output..Thank you